# Split Variable into two Variables at position

Tags: sas

I am looking for SAS code. I have data set with variable X which is a combination of letters and numbers. Here is an sample of what the data could look like, the actual data set has thousands of data points.

Variable X
B4000
941
323333
9879999
U28909

I'd Like to make a new variable in my data set called X1 which is the first three positions of X. That is X1 would read (B40, 941, 323,987,U28). Please let me know any quick functions I that could solve this problem. Would I use the scan function? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `SUBSTR` function, or define X1 to have a length of $3 and simply assign to it.

```
X1 = substr(x,1,3);  * length of X1 variable will be same as X but contain just 1st 3 chars ;
```

or

```
length X1 $3;  * specify explicit length of X1 variable;
X1 = X;        * truncation occurs on assignment;
```